# Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.Test

Tags: java, reflection, private

I was searching for how to access the private field of a class from other class and found that it can be done using reflect.Field as in the following code, but when i try to execute the code i get an error saying :`Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.Test`

why is it happening?

Test.java

```
package com.example;

import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        // Just for the ease of a throwaway test. Don't
        // do this normally!
        throws Exception
    {
        Other t = new Other();
        t.setStr("hi");
        Field field = Other.class.getDeclaredField("str");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(t);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Other.java

```
package com.example;

class Other
{
    private String str;
    public void setStr(String value)
    {
        str = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to run the class?

Comment: I Tried 'java Test' in cmd and also run it in netbeans.@BobbyStJacques

Comment: `java Test` wouldn't work as you'd need to specify the fully qualified class name (i.e. `java com.example.Test`).  However, your example output seems to indicate that you did specify the fully qualified class name (because the output mentions the full name).  My best guess is that you are trying to run from an arbitrary location without setting your Java classpath appropriately.  Your classpath tells Java where to search for your classes.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: ok , i've removed the package statements for both classes, compiled both of them and run test using 'java Test' and the result is the same.@BobbyStJacques

Comment: Are the .class files in the same directory from which you are running Java?

Answer (score 0):

> Compile both classes using **Javac**

```
javac Other.java

javac Test.java
```

> And run **Java Test**

While in eclipse you need to select Test class using run configuration option.

Comment: In Eclipse you can right-click on any class with a `main` and select Run As... Java Application (no need to build a run configuration unless you need to do something fancy like pass in command line arguments or Java system options).  But it's all moot because he's using Netbeans.